# how to create a excel unique that in case of delete a row continues with the next number?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to create excel a unique identifier that in case of deleting one row goes to the next row with a new number

for example:

```
scenario (1) Scenario (2)
1 a           1 a
2 b           3 c
3 c           4 e
4 e           5 a
```

Comment: Please provide more details like a working example. **It is very unclear as to what you are asking.** Also what have you tried? We are not going to simply make something for you. **What is your specific question?**

Comment: I just tried by adding a in every row (A+1) but in case, i have to delete one row this formula doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To delete rows do the procedure as follows:

1. Select the range of cells, or ensure that the active cell is in a table.

2. On the Data tab, click Remove Duplicates (in the Data Tools group).

3. Do one or more of the following: ...

4. Click OK, and a message will appear to indicate how many duplicate values were removed, or how many unique values remain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you mind sharing that example in an image?